# how to run map on avd Android Studio ide?

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-virtual-device

Good Morning Everyone,

I am trying to run map on my avd. But it gives me some errors. I am new On Android. Below is my steps:

1.My avd displays, Map1 won't run unless you update Google play services.

2.Run log displays:

```
W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 9877000 but found 9683270.
```

3.I have tried to search and found that I need to update my play services.

3.1. So I manually downloaded `apk` file and try to install it within `AVD`. but it won't work.

3.2. So I follow `SDKManager->AndroidSDK->SDKTools->and updated all`.

3.3. And `File->Project Structure->App->Dependencies->added Play Services Manually`.

3.4 Then at Last I try The Same Code with different AVD API 20-25 levels and get the same output:
'

> $ adb shell am start -n
>   "***********.map1/***********.map1.MapsActivity" -a
>   android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
>   Connected to process 4080 on device Nexus_4_API_22 [emulator-5554]
>   I/InstantRun: Instant Run Runtime started. Android package is
>   ***********.map1, real application class is null. W/art: Failed to find OatDexFile for DexFile
>   /data/data/**********.map1/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_2-classes.dex
>   ( canonical path
>   /data/data/***********.map1/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_2-classes.dex)
>   with checksum 0xfc12792c in OatFile
>   /data/data/*********.map1/cache/slice-slice_2-classes.dex
>   I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization unsuccessful
>   W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires
>   9877000 but found 9683270 W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play
>   services out of date.  Requires 9877000 but found 9683270
>   W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires
>   9877000 but found 9683270 W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play
>   services out of date.  Requires 9877000 but found 9683270
>   W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires
>   9877000 but found 9683270 W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play
>   services out of date.  Requires 9877000 but found 9683270
>   W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires
>   9877000 but found 9683270 W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play
>   services out of date.  Requires 9877000 but found 9683270
>   W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires
>   9877000 but found 9683270 W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play
>   services out of date.  Requires 9877000 but found 9683270
>   W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires
>   9877000 but found 9683270 W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play
>   services out of date.  Requires 9877000 but found 9683270
>   W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires
>   9877000 but found 9683270 D/OpenGLRenderer: Use
>   EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
>
> ```
>               [ 11-03 11:15:10.206  4080: 4080 D/         ]
>               HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa2c050d0, tid 4080 D/Atlas: Validating map...
> ```
>
> I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4 D/OpenGLRenderer:
>   Enabling debug mode 0 W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not
>   implemented W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on
>   surface 0xa2c065e0, error=EGL_SUCCESS`

4. My code works on my device properly. I want to run it on my AVD.

5.My AVD has:

5.1:

` Name: Nexus_5_API_21

```
CPU/ABI: Google APIs Intel Atom (x86)

Path: C:\**\*****\.android\avd\Nexus_5_API_21.avd

Target: google_apis [Google APIs] (API level 21)

Skin: nexus_5

SD Card: 100M

hw.dPad: no

runtime.network.speed: full

hw.accelerometer: yes

hw.device.name: Nexus 5

vm.heapSize: 64

skin.dynamic: yes

hw.device.manufacturer: Google

hw.gps: yes

hw.initialOrientation: Portrait

image.androidVersion.api: 21

hw.audioInput: yes

image.sysdir.1: system-images\android-21\google_apis\x86\

tag.id: google_apis

showDeviceFrame: yes

hw.camera.back: emulated

hw.mainKeys: no

AvdId: Nexus_5_API_21

hw.camera.front: emulated

hw.lcd.density: 480

avd.ini.displayname: Nexus 5 API 21

hw.gpu.mode: auto

hw.device.hash2: MD5:*********ceb7d385183***********

hw.ramSize: 1536

hw.trackBall: no

hw.battery: yes

hw.cpu.ncore: 2

hw.sdCard: yes

tag.display: Google APIs

runtime.network.latency: none

hw.keyboard: yes

hw.sensors.proximity: yes
1
disk.dataPartition.size: 800M

hw.sensors.orientation: yes

avd.ini.encoding: UTF-8

hw.gpu.enabled: yes`
```

[image: My AVD Display]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First try to update your AVD Services. if luck is with you then it will work and your map starts otherwise.

All You Need TO Do is Just Start The AVD and follow These :-

1. Go to settings->Apps->ALL->Google Play Services
   and Note the Version You have In your AVD.
2. now Open Your build.gradle(Module:app) not build.gradle(Project: '****') and change the Dependencies to the [compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:{Your Version of services}].

wish you Good luck ;)